# Cassandra list type conflicts

Tags: cassandra

If I have a [List](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html) field in Cassandra and two people write to it at the same time, is it a simple last write wins or will it merge the writes?

For example: [a, b, c, d]
User1 -> [b, a, c, d] (move b to index 0)
User2 -> [a, b, d, c] (move c to index 3)

Will Cassandra merge the results and end up with [b, a, d, c] or will it use last write wins to the microsecond?

Comment: What query are you using to write ?

Comment: Nothing yet. I'm just researching the technology. Do you know of one that would merge the writes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You will get the merge result**

Every write data to cassandra, a timestamp associated with each column is also inserted. when you execute read query, timestamps are used to pick a "winning" update within a single column or collection element.

What if I have a truly concurrent write with the same time stamp? In the unlikely case that you precisely end up with two time stamps that match in its microsecond, you might end up with a bad version but Cassandra ensures that ties are consistently broken by comparing the byte values.

Cassandra store list (collection) different than normal column.
Example :

```
CREATE TABLE friendlists (
    user text PRIMARY KEY,
    friends list <text>
);
```

If we insert some dummy data :

```
 user     | friends
----------+-------------------------
     john | [doug, patricia, scott]
 patricia |         [john, lucifer]
```

The internal representation:

```
RowKey: john
=> (column=, value=, timestamp=1374687324950000)
=> (column=friends:26017c10f48711e2801fdf9895e5d0f8, value='doug', timestamp=1374687206993000)
=> (column=friends:26017c11f48711e2801fdf9895e5d0f8, value='patricia', timestamp=1374687206993000)
=> (column=friends:26017c12f48711e2801fdf9895e5d0f8, value='scott', timestamp=1374687206993000)
=> (column=friends:6c504b60f48711e2801fdf9895e5d0f8, value='matt', timestamp=1374687324950000)
=> (column=friends:6c504b61f48711e2801fdf9895e5d0f8, value='eric', timestamp=1374687324950000)
-------------------
RowKey: patricia
=> (column=, value=, timestamp=1374687352290000)
=> (column=friends:3b817b80f48711e2801fdf9895e5d0f8, value='john', timestamp=1374687243064000)
```

Here the internal column name is more complicated because a UUID is appended to the name of the CQL field "friends". This is used to keep track of the order of items in the list.

Every time you insert data cassandra with below query :

```
INSERT INTO friendlists (user , friends ) VALUES ( 'patricia', ['john', 'lucifer']);
//or
UPDATE friendlists SET friends = ['john', 'lucifer']  where user =  'patricia';
```

Will create a tombstone with a less timestamp than current, it tells that the previous data has been deleted. So if concurrent insert happened with the same exact timestamp both data are ahead of tombstone so both data will live.

Source :
http://mighty-titan.blogspot.com/2012/06/understanding-cassandras-consistency.html
http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2013/07/24/understanding-how-cql3-maps-to-cassandras-internal-data-structure-sets-lists-and-maps/